# How to keep changes in made in the vendor folder in Heroku?

Tags: laravel, heroku, composer-php, vendor

I am trying to run a Laravel project in Heroku. I have made some changes to on some file in the vendor. When I push my code to Heroku, all my changes are gone then. How do I keep the changes I have made to the `vendor` folder?

Comment: Never edit what is inside the vendor directory. Create your own method to meet your need. What are the changes you made to the vendor directory ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, and you must not change anything in `vendor` or any other package manager.